# Display name of user all users who have liked a particular post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to name(s) of all user who have liked a post.

I have 4 models: user,post,like and review.

A user can have many posts.
Post can reviews && post can have many likes.

I am able to count likes on post but i am not able to display name of users who have liked a post.

**Like Model:**

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

**Review Model:**

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end
```

**User Model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  has_secure_password

  has_many :posts
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :likes

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.new_record? && a.password.blank? }

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:reset_password_token)
    self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end


  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end

end[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

**_post.html.erb**

```
<h1> Posts ( <%= @posts.count %> ) </h1>
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
    <div class="form-field">

        <h4>
            <b><%= p.title %></b>
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(p.id), class: "btn btn-warning col-md-2-offset", style: "align-right" %> 
            <%= link_to "Delete", p, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger col-md-2-offset" ,data: { confirm: "You sure? "}, style: "align-right" %> 
            <% if p.reviews.count > 0 %>
                 <%= link_to "View Comments", review_path(p.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
        </h4> 
        <%= p.body %>
        <br>
            <% if p.likes.count > 0 %>
               Likes: <%= p.likes.count %>
            <% end %>
        <br>
            <% if Like.find_by(user_id: current_user.id,post_id: p.id) %>
               <%= link_to " UnLike ", like_path(p.id), method: :delete,class: "btn btn- 
   primary fa fa-thumbs-down" %>
            <% else %>
               <%= link_to " Like ", post_likes_path(p.id), method: :post, class: "btn btn- 
    primary fa fa-thumbs-up" %>
            <% end %>
        <br> 
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I was trying something like this, 
[image]

I need to connect user,like and post table, for post which has been liked by some user. 
I somehow need to merge two-three queries.

Comment: I'm confused. Your title says something, but the question shows something else. Can you explain further what's the question?

Comment: Don't use multiple version tags on your question. Misusing them won't get your question any more attention.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the names of users that have liked a post to display them? If that's the case you can add a function to one of your controllers called something like `get_likes_for(post_id)` that will return an array of all the users that liked a post:

```
def get_likes_for(pid)
  users = []
  Like.where(post_id: pid).each do |l|
    users << User.find_by(id: l.user_id).name
  end
  users
end
```

Then you can list them in your post controller like this:

```
<% if p.likes.count > 0 %>
    Likes: <%= p.likes.count %>
    Liked By: <%= get_likes_for(p.id).to_s %>
<% end %>
```

This won't exactly connect the three models like the last part of your posts asks, but it will at least allow you to display the users who have liked a post.

Comment: This is gonna make more SQL queries than needed or expected.

Answer (score 0):

@like is an array, 
instead use 
@like = @liked.where(post_id: 7).first

Then try @like.user

Comment: `@liked.find_by(post_id: 7)`

Answer (score 0):

- First I hope you use eager loading to prevent the [N+1 issue](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), when loading *likes* of a post, and their *users*
- Second

  I would suggest changing this peace of code

  ```
      <% if Like.find_by(user_id: current_user.id,post_id: p.id) %>
         <%= link_to " UnLike ", like_path(p.id), method: :delete,class: "btn btn-primary fa fa-thumbs-down" %>
      <% else %>
         <%= link_to " Like ", post_likes_path(p.id), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary fa fa-thumbs-up" %>
      <% end %>
  ```

  With

  ```
      <% if p.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) %>
         <%= link_to " UnLike ", like_path(p.id), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-primary fa fa-thumbs-down" %>
      <% else %>
         <%= link_to " Like ", post_likes_path(p.id), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary fa fa-thumbs-up" %>
      <% end %>
  ```

  This will not perform additional *DB* request
- And finnally how to shows user name of each user that has liked the post
  I would suggest creating a helper method for this, as it may be need for multiple places

  ```
  def liked_by_users(post)
     post.likes.map do |like|
        like.user.username
     end.join(', ')
  end
  ```

Comment: You can do `Like.exists?(user_id: current_user.id,post_id: p.id)` instead of `find_by`. After all, you're not using the records as a result from that query.

Comment: Have you actually tested this code? `.find_by` will always create a SQL query even if the relation is loaded.